# Transfer files from IBM Cloud Object storage to Azure blob

Tags: azure, ibm-cloud, cloud-object-storage

Hi I want to migrate a huge volume of files as a cronjob from my IBM Cloud Object Storage to Azure. Simplest way is to download from IBM cloud to some intermediate server and upload it to Azure. But, is there any solution available which will copy the files from IBM COS to Azure directly. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: you could try to use the S3 API on the IBM Cloud storage with Azure Data Factory https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-amazon-simple-storage-service?tabs=data-factory

Comment: Thanks @silent I will give a try.

Comment: @ShantanuMitra were you able to find any solution to this? Does IBM COS works with azcopy?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way how to upload your files directly from IBM to Azure blob,

- Rclone can do it(a command-line program)
- Precog ( allow you to move data from IBM Cloud Object Storage to Azure Blob Storage directly )
- AWS CLI ( as silent said, you can use the S3 API on the IBM Cloud storage with Azure Data Factory)
- Gs Richcopy ( GUI tool which can be used to transfer directly from IBM cloud to Azure blob )
- SyncBack Pro (lightweight GUI tool which can be used to transfer directly from IBM cloud to Azure blob ).

Answering @ShantanuMitra , Azcopy is workable with Azure storage but I didn't find a way to use it to transfer directly from IBM cloud to Azure blob